# Will tar overwrite my home folder

Tags: backup, tar, restore

I'm using `tar` to backup and restore my Ubuntu system.

For my Ubuntu system, I mount `/` to `dev/sda1` and mount `/home` to `dev/sda2`. I want to backup or restore `/` without `/home`.

To backup, I execute

```
cd ~ && sudo tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude /home --one-file-system /
```

Then I install some packages, for example, `apt install ubuntu-desktop`.

Now I want to restore my system with `backup.tar.gz`. So I execute

```
sudo tar -xvpzf backup.tar.gz -C / --numeric-owner
```

My questions are:

1. Will this remove all files from `apt install ubuntu-desktop`?
2. Will this touch my home folder? I'm wondering if this will clean all files in my home folder.

Comment: As far as I can see, no (both questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use it to extract a tarball, `tar` (by default) doesn’t delete files. This largely answers both your questions: the files added by installing `ubuntu-desktop` will be untouched, as will the contents of `/home`. Extracting the backup will however restore any files the tarball contains, which means the system’s package databases will be returned to their state before you installed `ubuntu-desktop`.

If you want to have a fully reversible package installation, you should use snapshots instead.